# YouTube API v3 - upload video

Tags: c++, qt, youtube-api, google-api-cpp-client

I would like load myVideo.avi on YouTube with my Qt5 programm. I successful authorisation through OAuth 2.0 and get access_token without errors.

But when I try to use API https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert 
I get some erros!

```
QString googleApiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?access_token="+authorisation->getAccessToken()+"&part=snippet";

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(googleApiUrl));

    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::MixedType);

    QHttpPart videoPart;
    videoPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("video/*"));
    videoPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("Slug"));

    m_video = new QFile(m_filePath);
    if (m_video->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        videoPart.setBodyDevice(m_video);
    }
    multiPart->append(videoPart);


    m_networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    m_networkManager->post(request,multiPart);
    connect(m_networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(handleNetworkReply(QNetworkReply*)));
```

response-

```
"Host requires authentication"
"{
"error": {
 "errors": [
  {
   "domain": "youtube.header",
   "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",
   "message": "Unauthorized",
   "locationType": "header",
   "location": "Authorization"
  }
 ],
 "code": 401,
 "message": "Unauthorized"
}
}
"
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: I don't see how you go through OAuth2 or apply your token into the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`youtubeSignupRequired` means that you're going through the OAuth 2 flow and authorizing access using a Google Account that doesn't have a YouTube channel associated with it yet. I'd recommend going through the flow again and confirming that you're authorizing access using the correct account.

As an aside, I'd recommend giving https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client a try. It's fairly new and may simplify your code vs. making the raw HTTP calls yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the solution in this question:

[YouTube Data API v3 video upload 403 forbidden: YouTubeSignUpRequired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453505/youtube-data-api-v3-video-upload-403-forbidden-youtubesignuprequired)

Catch the error and send the user to this YouTube site:

https://m.youtube.com/create_channel?chromeless=1&next=/channel_creation_done