# youtube api 401 error youtubeSigupRequired

Tags: python, api, youtube-api

I am trying to upload a video to Youtube using Youtube API v3 and python and I got the following error.

An HTTP error 401 occurred:

```
{  "error": {   "errors": [    {
    "domain": "youtube.header",
    "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"    }   ],   "code": 401,   "message": "Unauthorized"  } }
```

I have created my project, created my Key and Client AOuth 2.0 and google console and downloaded the client_secrets.json.

The code I run is the one provided by Youtube API sample_code to download ([here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)) for python.

If for example I try to do a search using the corresponding sample code and my credentials it works perfectly and I don't know why it doesn't work when I want to upload a vide.

Could you please letting me know what I am doing wrong, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please go through with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14492382/3020426

Answer (score 6):

[YouTube Data API - Errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)

> unauthorized (401)    youtubeSignupRequired   This error indicates that the
>   user has an unlinked Google Account, which means that the user has a
>   [Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441?visit_id=1-636256157294098454-873619818&rd=1) but does not have a YouTube channel. Such users can
>   access many features that are dependent on user authorization, such as
>   rating videos or adding videos to a watch_later playlist. However, as
>   an example, the user would need a YouTube channel to be able to upload
>   a video. A user who has a Gmail account or an Android device is
>   certain to have a Google Account but may not have already linked that
>   Google Account to a YouTube channel.
>
> This error is commonly seen if you try to use the OAuth 2.0 Service
>   Account flow. YouTube does not support Service Accounts, and if you
>   attempt to authenticate using a Service Account, you will get this
>   error.
>
> The YouTube API blog post introducing Google Account support also
>   discusses the youtubeSignupRequired error in more detail. Although the
>   blog post explains the error for API version 2.1, the meaning of the
>   error is still applicable.

Comment: before I posted this I tried with Google Account, creating project, OAuth 2.0, etc and I got the same error...

Comment: You need to go to YouTube and link your google Account to that.  You need to create a channel on youtube.

Comment: I have done before posted this question. Still not working!!

Comment: After I created channel it worked like a charm, thank you @DaImTo